# How to set a flag to the max number of a group?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, max

This is the query:

```
SELECT WorkTypeId, WorktypeWorkID, LevelID
    FROM Worktypes as w
    LEFT JOIN WorktypesWorks as ww on w.ID = ww.WorktypeID
    LEFT JOIN WorktypesWorksLevels as wwl on ww.ID = wwl.WorktypeWorkID
```

This is the result:

```
WorkTypeId  WorktypeWorkID  LevelID
1           1               1
1           1               2
1           1               3
1           2               1
1           2               2
1           2               3
1           3               1
1           4               1
1           4               2
1           5               1
NULL        NULL            NULL
3           19              2
4           6               1
4           7               1
4           7               2
4           7               3
4           17              1
4           17              2
4           18              1
4           18              2
NULL            NULL        NULL
```

I'd like to add a new column called "MaxLevel" only to the row where the LevelID (for each WorktypeWorkID group having the same WorkTypeId), settings value 1 when the LevelID is the MAX number in the group by, 0 otherwise.

Here's the result that I'd like to get:

```
WorkTypeId  WorktypeWorkID  LevelID     MaxLevel
1           1               1           0
1           1               2           0
1           1               3           1 // 3 is the max on the group
1           2               1           0
1           2               2           0
1           2               3           1 // 3 is the max on the group
1           3               1           1 // 1 is the max on the group
1           4               1           0
1           4               2           1 // 2 is the max on the group
1           5               1           1 // 1 is the max on the group
NULL        NULL            NULL        0
3           19              2           1 // 2 is the max on the group
4           6               1           1 // 1 is the max on the group
4           7               1           0
4           7               2           0
4           7               3           1 // 3 is the max on the group
4           17              1           0
4           17              2           1 // 2 is the max on the group
4           18              1           0
4           18              2           1 // 2 is the max on the group
NULL            NULL        NULL        0
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Isn't this just a case of comparing the value `LevelID` to (a windowed) `MAX(LevelID)`?

Comment: @Larnu: no, check the row 13 for example. LevelID could be higher rather than the number of values in the group

Comment: "row 13" isn't easy to discern when there's no row numbers.

Comment: @Larnu maybe you are right, try to reply with an answer and I'll check it out, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little tricky because of the `NULL` values.  So I think you want:

```
(case when levelid = max(levelid) over (partition by WorkTypeId, WorktypeWorkID) and
           WorktypeWorkID is not null
      then 1 else 0
 end) as maxlevel
```

Comment: Considering that `NULL = NULL` is unknown, and therefore not true, the `and WorktypeWorkID is not null` is actually redundant here. Unless, of course, you have `SET ANSI_NULLS OFF`, but that's a can of worms you should not be opening as the functionality is due to be removed from SQL Server (as highlighted in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-nulls-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)).

Comment: @Larnu . . . I don't get your point.  `NULL` values are allowed for partitioning clauses.  And in the sample data, the `NULL` values have valid `levelid`s.

Comment: In all instances where `WorktypeWorkID` has a value of `NULL` both `WorkTypeId` and `WorktypeWorkID` do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a window function:

```
SELECT
  WorkTypeId, 
  WorktypeWorkID, 
  LevelID,
  case when LevelId = max(LevelId) over(partition by WorktypeWorkID) then 1
       else 0
  end as MaxLevel
FROM Worktypes as w
LEFT JOIN WorktypesWorks as ww on w.ID = ww.WorktypeID
LEFT JOIN WorktypesWorksLevels as wwl on ww.ID = wwl.WorktypeWorkID
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just a `CASE` expression and a windowed `MAX`, like I mentioned in the comment:

```
SELECT V.WorkTypeId,
       V.WorktypeWorkID,
       V.LevelID,
       CASE V.LevelID WHEN MAX(V.LevelID) OVER (PARTITION BY V.WorkTypeId, WorktypeWorkID) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS MaxLevel
FROM (VALUES(1,1,1),
            (1,1,2),
            (1,1,3),
            (1,2,1),
            (1,2,2),
            (1,2,3),
            (1,3,1),
            (1,4,1),
            (1,4,2),
            (1,5,1),
            (NULL,NULL,NULL),
            (3,19,2),
            (4,6,1),
            (4,7,1),
            (4,7,2),
            (4,7,3),
            (4,17,1),
            (4,17,2),
            (4,18,1),
            (4,18,2),
            (NULL,NULL,NULL))V(WorkTypeId,WorktypeWorkID,LevelID);
```